# Initializing a map in firestore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build an app using react native with a firestore database. I'm fairly new to the react native framework (as well as working with firestore), so it's possible I might be trying to solve this problem the wrong way.

I have a database that works well and is already populated. For each user of this app, I'd like to add a `map` to their entry. I want to use this `map` to store some data about the user which they can fill out later.

Here's some code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.readProfile(this.props.uid);
}

readProfile = (uid) => {
  this.props.getProfile(uid).then((profile) => 
  {
    if(!profile.userMap)
    {
      profile.userMap = generateUserMap();
    }
...
}

export const generateUserMap = function () {
  var map = new Map();
  SomeEnum.forEach((key, value) => {
    map.set(key, false);
  });
  AnotherEnum.forEach((key, value) => {
    map.set(key, false);
  });
  OneMoreEnum.forEach((key, value) => {
    map.set(key, false);
  });
  return map;
};

...

<Input
 value={this.state.profile.userMap[SomeEnum.Foo]}
 onChangeText={(foo) => this.updateUserMap({ foo })}
/>
```

What I want this code to be doing is to read in the user's profile when I load the page. That part seems to be working fine. My next concern is to properly initialize the `map` object. The code doesn't seem to be properly initializing the map, but I'm not sure why. Here's why I say that:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Foo' of undefined

With the stack trace pointing to my component's `Connect()` method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies for the oversight, here is the updateUserMap function:

```
updateUserMap = (property) => {
  const profile = Object.assign({}, this.state.profile, property);
  this.setState({ profile });
}
```

Comment: where is `updateUserMap ` function??

Comment: As @hongdevelop said, please could you give us the implementation of updateUserMap function ?

Comment: @hongdevelop Sure, sorry for overlooking that! Updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, as anyone who looks over this question can probably tell, I was doing a few things pretty wrong.

The error I'm getting referred specifically to that input block in my render method - this.state.profile.userMap was undefined at that point. I can guarantee that it won't be undefined if I do my check within the render method but before I'm accessing the userMap. Because of how the lifecycle methods work in react native, ComponentDidMount wouldn't be called before my render method would.

My enum code also wouldn't work. I changed that to a simple for loop and it works like a charm.

Here's my updated code:

```
  render() {
    if(!this.state.profile.userMap)
    {
      this.state.profile.userMap = generateUserMap();
    }
```